# Prove that if $\int_0^1 f(yx) dx = g(y)$, so $f(x)=g(x)+xg'(x)$ for any $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, smooth-functions

I'm trying to solve this question:

> $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is of $C^1$ class, such that $g(y) = \int_0^1 f(yx) dx$. Prove that $f(x)=g(x)+xg'(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

But my progress until now was really slow. I've tried to use the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) and the [first mean value theorem for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals), but I had no success. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Make the substitution $t=yx$ in the integral.

Comment: Hint:  the right side is the deriviative of $xg(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change variables in the integral ($u = xy$), you get
$$
\int_0^1 f(yx) dx = \frac 1y \int_0^yf(u) du,
$$

so,
$$\int_0^y f(u) dy = yg(y) \Rightarrow f(y)=(yg(y))' = g(y) + yg'(y).$$

Note: This method requires that $y\ne 0$, but in that case the equality can be checked directly.

Comment: Oh, so simple! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

welcome toi MSE .  a hint can be $$f(x)=g(x)+xg'(x)\\
f(x)=x'g(x)+xg'(x)\\f(x)=(xg(x))'\\\to \\\int f(x)=xg(x)+const$$